# Nestjs middleware does not throw any errors

Tags: node.js, nestjs

Normally in express, any middleware can call next with an optional error, as per the normal node-js callback conventions.

But, when I return error inside of a NestMiddleware, the error is not handled at all. The error is not logged or returned, it is swallowed and the request does not terminate.

Here is the sample code:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthenticateMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
  async use(req: Request | any, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    console.log(
      chalk.magentaBright.bold('Authenticate Middleware Executing...'),
    );

    let token: string;
    if (
      !req.headers.authorization ||
      !req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
    ) {
      return new UnauthorizedException('Please login to continue');
    } else {
      token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    }

    let isValid: { id: string; iat: number; exp: number };
    try {
      isValid = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    } catch (e) {
      return new UnauthorizedException('Token invalid!');
    }

    req.userId = isValid.id;
    next();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're `return`ing errors, meaning the system thinks what has been returned is fine. If you want to actually have an error happen, you should `throw` the error instead. You could make the same argument that

```js
sayHello() {
 return new BadRequestException('Goodby World');
}
```

doesn't throw an error, because it doesn't. You should be using the `throw` keyword for a later system to `catch` it and handle it properly

Comment: Is it a good practice to use ```throw``` instead of ```return``` everywhere?
Basically, I am just asking where should I use ```return``` and where should I use ```throw``` when it comes to handle errors ?

Comment: `return` when you have a value. `throw` when you have an error. Nest's `ExceptionFilter` will catch the error so long as it's in the request lifecycle

Answer (score 3):

In the catch block:

```
const errPayload =  new UnauthorizedException('Token invalid!');
next(errPayload)
```